# PyQGIS Filling in empty fields in attribute table

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I want to fill in all my empty fields in the attribute table with a 0 because otherwise i cant use the sum-function properbly. I tried to iterate through all the fields and store every empty field in a list. Then i wanted to add a 0 to every field in that list. Doing so my script looks like this:

```
layer = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Kriterien.shp'
nulllists = [field for field in layer.fields if field.isEmpty()]
nulllists.setComment('0')
layer.updateFields()
```

It is not working like this and I wonder if maybe setComment is the wrong method or do you have any idea what else could be wrong with my script?

Comment: All fields are numeric?

Comment: Yes they're all numeric

Comment: Which sum function are you talking about that doesnt work with empty fields?

Comment: from the field calculator

Comment: If it cant handle the nulls you can try `sum( coalesce("field1", 0), coalesce("field2", 0))`. Coalesce will return the first not null, so if the fields value is null it will return 0

Answer (score 2):

You can try this short script in the Python console. I advise to make a backup copy of the layer first, just as a precaution. This will replace any NULL values with 0 in all numeric fields in your layer.

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Kriterien.shp'
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(path, '', 'ogr')
if lyr.isValid():
    fld_names = [f.name() for f in lyr.fields() if f.isNumeric()]
    with edit(lyr):
        for ft in lyr.getFeatures():
            for fld_name in fld_names:
                if ft[fld_name] == NULL:
                    ft[fld_name] = 0
            lyr.updateFeature(ft)
```

Here is an example of how this can be adapted to a custom processing script, which you can save as a python file and add to the processing toolbox. This script will create an new output layer as opposed to editing the existing layer in place.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsFeatureSink, QgsFeatureRequest,
    QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
    QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, NULL)
                       
class FillNullsWithZero(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def name(self):
        return "fillNULLS"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("fillNULLS", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Fill NULLS with zero")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Fill NULL numeric values with zeros")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
   
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.INPUT,
            self.tr("Input layer"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            self.OUTPUT,
            self.tr("Output layer"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry))
 
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context,
                                               source.fields(), source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())
        field_names = [f.name() for f in source.fields() if f.isNumeric()]
        features = source.getFeatures()
        for feat in features:
            out_feat = QgsFeature()
            out_feat.setGeometry(feat.geometry())
            out_feat.setFields(feat.fields())
            out_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
            for field_name in field_names:
                if feat[field_name] == NULL:
                    out_feat.setAttribute(field_name, 0)
            sink.addFeature(out_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
 
        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think the script would also work as a part in a processing script? I think 'edit' isn't defined there, but maybe i just have to revise it a little bit

Comment: @Anni98, I added an example to my answer. By the way, if this answer helped you (and any other answers you have received for that matter) a gentle reminder about: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the reminder to vote up helpful answers.